# Python invalid syntax on define

Tags: python, syntax

I made a piece of code for taking the cpu temp for my rpi and if it's more than 60 C to send a signal on GPIO port 7 and if it's not more than 60 C to not send the signal on the port but I get this error:

```
 File "tempgate.py", line 17
    def FanController(CPU_temp) :
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The file is:

```
#Module import and variables
import getinfo
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import atexit
import datetime
CPU_temp = getinfo.getCPUtemperature
#Start info
st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print("[LOG] [" + st + "] Program has started")
#Setup and definitions
try:
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)

def FanController(CPU_temp) :
    CPU_temp = int(float(CPU_temp))
    print(CPU_temp)
    if(int(CPU_temp) > int(60)) :
        GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
        ts = time.time()
        st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        print("[LOG] [" + st + "] Fan is now on")
        time.sleep(5)
    else :
        GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN)
        ts = time.time()
        st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        print("[LOG] [" + st + "] Fan is now off")
        time.sleep(5)

#main app
while True :
    CPU_temp = getinfo.getCPUtemperature()
    print("[LOG] [" + st + "] Cpu CPU_temp is: " + CPU_temp)
    FanController(CPU_temp)
GPIO.cleanup()
atexit.register(GPIO.cleanup())
```

Comment: `try` must have an `except` countepart...

Comment: Add an `except: pass` after your try block.

Comment: you need to add `except` block before the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unclosed `try...` block unmatched with `except`.

Comment: should probably be a comment. Typo questions like that aren't worth the trouble. Any decent editor like PyCharm is able to detect those...